# Grails Criteria not working in JUnit Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, grails-2.0

I'm trying to test search method in my grails app but I'm having a null pointer exception. I mocked the domain in my test as follows:

```
  @TestFor(AuditController)
  @Mock(Audit)
  class AuditControllerTests {

void testSearch() {

    populateValidParams(params)
    def audit=new Audit(params)
    audit.save(failOnError: true)

    //Search existing customer
    def model = controller.search()
    assert model.auditInstanceList.size() == 1
    assert model.auditInstanceList.size() == 1

}
  }
```

I got NPE on model.auditInstanceList. Where it shouldn't be null. Here is the code in my controller:

```
def search = {

    def query
    def criteria = Audit.createCriteria()
    def results

    query = {
        and{
            if(params.customerName){
                ilike("customerName", params.customer + '%')
            }
            if(params.siteName){
                ilike("siteName", params.siteName + '%')
            }
            max:params.max
            offset:params.offset


        }
    }

    results = criteria.list(params, query)


    render(view:'list', model:[ auditInstanceList: results,auditInstanceTotal:results.totalCount ])

}
```

What is going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but sometimes you need to remove model as a return value from controller's action. I use both version alternatively in case one of them fails:

```
// sometimes this one works
def model = controller.search()
assert model

// sometimes this one works 
controller.search()
assert model
```

Edit: I think of two new possibilities why your action doesn't work:

1. try to change your action from closure and make it a method.
2. make sure you have no after filter. I've found this bug: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6825

Comment: I don't know. There are some JIRA issues regarding it like this: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8462 .

Answer (score 0):

Return `model` at the end of `search`. As in,

```
def search = {
  ...
  render(view:'list', model:[ auditInstanceList: results, auditInstanceTotal:results.totalCount ])

  [auditInstanceList: results, auditInstanceTotal:results.totalCount]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing a controller action that calls `render()`, `model` and `view` variables are automatically created and populated in your test. By doing `def model = controller.search()`, you are replacing the magic `model` with your own, assigning it to the return value of `search()`. The correct way to do your assertions is:

```
controller.search()
assert model.auditInstanceList.size() == 1
assert view == '/audit/list'
```